# Title and button text change on media uploader

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am using wordpress latest version. I want to change the title and button text on the post featured image uploader. Is there any way to do this??? Can anyone help me...... Please.....

[image]

Comment: Can't you just edit the source file?

Comment: Please click on the link "enter image description here". here I attach an image. This will helpful for you to understand that what I mean.

Comment: I don't want to do this. I managed a custom plugin and I want to manage this from my plugin.

Comment: Is thers any hook to manage this?